# 'ListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

not quite sure what this is about but I had something that worked just fine outside of Monaca, and once in Monaca I get this:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Here is the code:

```
<script>
var app = ons.bootstrap('propertyDeal', ['onsen']);
app.factory('Property', function () {

    /**
    * Constructor, with class name
    */
    function Property(newProperty) {
        // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
        this.purchasePrice = newProperty.pprice;
        this.marketValue = newProperty.mv;
        this.stampDuty = newProperty.stamp;
        this.sourcingFee = newProperty.sourcing;
        this.legaFee = newProperty.legal;
        this.otherFee = newProperty.other;
      }

    /**
    * Public method, assigned to prototype
    */
    Property.prototype.getPurchasePrice = function () {
        return this.purchasePrice;
    };

    return {
        createNew: function(newProperty) {
            console.log( "Alert accomplished" );
            return new Property(newProperty);
        }
    };
});

app.factory('portfolio', function(Property){
    var portfolio = {};
    portfolio.list = [];

    portfolio.add = function(newProperty){
        var prop = Property.createNew(newProperty);
        portfolio.list.push(prop);
        alert(prop.purchasePrice);
    };

    return portfolio;
}); 

app.controller('ListCtrl', function(portfolio) {
    var self = this;
    self.portfolio = portfolio.list;
});

app.controller('PostCtrl', function(portfolio){
    var self = this;

    self.addProperty = function(newProperty){
        portfolio.add(newProperty);
    }; 
});

</script>

<ons-navigator>
<ons-page>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="TopMenuController" ng-init="init('Initial investment','ion-social-usd')">
        <div ng-include="url"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>Initial investment</h2>

        <ul class="list">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="newProperty.id" placeholder="id">
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.pprice" placeholder="Purchase price">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.mv" placeholder="Market value">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.stamp" placeholder="Stamp duty">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.sourcing" placeholder="Sourcing fee">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.legal" placeholder="Legal fee">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" ng-model="newProperty.other" placeholder="Other">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div data-ng-controller="ListCtrl as list">
        <p ng-repeat="prop in list.portfolio track by $index">
            New Object: {{prop.purchasePrice}}: {{prop.legaFee}} </p>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl as post">
        <input type="button" ng-click="post.addProperty(newProperty)" value="Create Property"></input>
        <p>{{newProperty}}</p>
    </div>
 </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this knowing that the exact same code is working when tested in a fiddle for example
http://jsfiddle.net/XmWUP/129/

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where are you defining your app? There isn't a `var app = angular.module('name', []);` Does it have the empty array? That can cause this error if its missing and you haven't already defined it. The array tells angular 'create this module' otherwise it says 'find me this module'. Also sorry this is a pet hate but there is no need to alias `this` as `self` in your code.

Comment: thanks ste2425. The bootstrap was on another pahe, i've added it, which is a tiny bit different with onsen-ui but does the same thing than the module declaration if I understand well.
I know about self and this, but edited some code earlier that made it unnecessary and didn't change it, but as you said, this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except for `ng-controller="TopMenuController"`, which is not defined.

Probably the issue is related with Angular version, your jsfiddle example uses `1.2.6` but Monaca uses `1.4.3` with `Onsen UI 1.3.11`.

Check this [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/rOZbpo).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TopMenuController is defined in another page, I just coppied the page.

Comment: I thought it would be because of the different version but I don't understand how that can change and how to make it work with this version.
I don't see how your codepen is any different to my code apart from the fact that it runs on 1.3.11

Comment: Onsen UI 1.x is based on Angular and some elements have been deprecated/changed/added from Angular 1.2 to 1.4, that's probably why.